# Test HTTP response with PlayFramework/JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I've been looking for hours to find a way to test if a route is correct with play. 
I mean, for exemple

> Is the GET request to `localhost:9000/test` actually return `200 OK`?

I was not able to find any working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Play's WS (Web Services) library to achieve this. For Example:

```
package endpoints;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import models.Meh;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.ws.WS;
import play.libs.ws.WSResponse;
import play.test.TestServer;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

public class MehEndpointTest {

    private static long timeout;
    private static Meh meh1;
    private static Meh meh2;
    // Test Server
    private static TestServer testServer = testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()));
    private static JsonNode meh1Node;
    private static JsonNode meh2Node;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        timeout = 10000L;
        // Dummy Objects
        meh1 = new Meh();
        meh1.meh = "foo";
        meh1.yo = "bar";
        meh2 = new Meh();
        meh2.meh = "hell";
        meh2.yo = "world";
        meh1Node = Json.toJson(meh1);
        meh2Node = Json.toJson(meh2);
        // Start the server
        start(testServer);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        WSResponse wsResponse1 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh").post(meh1Node).get(timeout);
        WSResponse wsResponse2 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh").post(meh2Node).get(timeout);
        JsonNode jsonNode1 = wsResponse1.asJson();
        JsonNode jsonNode2 = wsResponse2.asJson();
        assertThat(wsResponse1.getStatus()).isEqualTo(CREATED);
        assertThat(wsResponse2.getStatus()).isEqualTo(CREATED);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.isObject()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.get("id").asLong()).isEqualTo(1L);
        assertThat(jsonNode2.isObject()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(jsonNode2.get("id").asLong()).isEqualTo(2L);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() {
        WSResponse wsResponse1 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh").get().get(timeout);
        WSResponse wsResponse2 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh/2").get().get(timeout);
        JsonNode jsonNode1 = wsResponse1.asJson();
        JsonNode jsonNode2 = wsResponse2.asJson();
        assertThat(wsResponse1.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(wsResponse2.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.isArray()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(jsonNode2.isObject()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(jsonNode1).hasSize(2);
        assertThat(jsonNode2.get("id").asLong()).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        meh1.id = 1L;
        meh1.yo = "changed yo";
        WSResponse wsResponse1 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh/1").put(Json.toJson(meh1)).get(timeout);
        JsonNode jsonNode1 = wsResponse1.asJson();
        assertThat(wsResponse1.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.isObject()).isEqualTo(true);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.get("id").asLong()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(jsonNode1.get("yo").asText()).isEqualTo("changed yo");
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        WSResponse wsResponse1 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh").post(meh1Node).get(timeout);
        WSResponse wsResponse2 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh/3").delete().get(timeout);
        WSResponse wsResponse3 = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/api/meh").get().get(timeout);
        JsonNode jsonNode1 = wsResponse3.asJson();
        assertThat(wsResponse1.getStatus()).isEqualTo(CREATED);
        assertThat(wsResponse2.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(wsResponse3.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(jsonNode1).hasSize(2);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        // Stop the server
        stop(testServer);
    }
}
```

Notice the calls to `assertThat(wsResponse1.getStatus()).isEqualTo(OK);`

Hope that helps. Leave a comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: Wow. Many, many thanks. Just wonder one thing: My server is actually running on localhost:9000 (so Ws.url("http://localhost:9000"). What is the 3333 in testServer 1st argument?

Comment: its the port number that the fake application/server would use so you can change it to 9000 if you like. However if you need to run the application at the same time as the tests then of course you need to have them different to avoid "Address in use" errors.

Comment: So, I do not need my localhost:9000 server to run in order to perform the tests?

Comment: No, the routes would remain the same regardless of the port number. So if you have a route `localhost:9000/test` in your regular application then there is an corresponding route in the test server as `localhost:3333/test`

Comment: Powerful. Thak's for all the help!